# If a complex analytic function is nonzero at a point, then this point is not an extremum of its modulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic and  ${f}'(z)\neq 0$ in  a  region $\Omega$. If $z_{0}  \in \Omega$ and  $f(z_{0})\neq 0$, show  that  for  all   $\varepsilon > 0$,  there  are  $z_{1},z_{2}$ such    that $\left | z_{1}-z_{0} \right |< \varepsilon$, $\left | z_{1}-z_{2} \right |< \varepsilon$,   and $$\left | f(z_{1}) \right |>\left | f(z_{0}) \right |> \left | f(z_{2}) \right |$$

I have thought by mapping of 2-balls, or open maps but I have no certainty.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open mapping theorem yields this result. The image of the open disk $D = \{z: |z-z_0|<\epsilon\}$ contains a neighborhood of $f(z_0)$. Hence, it contains the points $(1+\delta)f(z_0)$ and $(1-\delta) f(z_0)$ when $\delta$ is small enough. Use the preimages of these points as $z_1$ and $z_2$ to achieve $|f(z_1)|>|f(z_0)|>|f(z_2)|$.

Comment: Corollary : The fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: You can  use the Cauchy-Riemann integral to show that if |f(z)| is a non-0 local minimum of |f|, then |f| is constant in a ndhd of  z ,which implies that f is constant.

Comment: but f constant not imply the inequalities in module